# extend an array with repeated values until another array values matches MATLAB

Tags: matlab

```
a=[2 3 4 7 9 12 15 18 22]
b=[2 7 15]
```

The result should be like this

```
c=[2 2 2  7 7 7 15 15 15];
```

The values should repeat until another matrix values matches. How can Matlab get me a solution for all problems related to this? Kindly help..

Comment: Can we assume that `a` and `b` are sorted to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `a` and `b` are sorted, you can try this

```
c = b(sum(bsxfun(@(x,y) x >= y, a, b(:))));
```

This results in

```
c =
     2     2     2     7     7     7    15    15    15
```

Please note that this works only if `b(1) == a(1)`. If `b(1) < a(1)`, `b(1)` will be repeated although it does not match `a(1)` and if `b(1) > a(1)` an error is thrown because a subscript index is smaller than 1.

Comment: Thank you for your reply....the previous post is enough for my work and it will be more useful for me...the condition b(1)==a(1) always satisfies..no problem.thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the first two numbers are always the same (otherwise what should the first number of the result be?):

```
prevj = b(1);
last = 1;
c = a;
for j = b(2:end)
    ind = find(c == j);
    c(last:ind-1) = prevj;
    last = ind;
    prevj = j;
end
c(last:end) = prevj;
```

Sorry about the messy code, but it seems to get the results you want (with a few assumptions).